# Launch Clipboard History (Win+V keyboard shortcut) through CLI

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, clipboard

Is there a way to open the Windows 10 Clipboard History through the command line? E.g., `explorer.exe ms-screenclip:` opens up the Screen Clip in Windows 10.

I also didn't find anything in `regedit`. `HCU\Software\Microsoft\Clipboard` nor `HLM\Software\Microsoft\Clipboard` have anything regarding path of EXE.

All I'm trying to do is make a shortcut for it. Any help is appreciated.

Info on Clipboard History can be found here: https://www.howtogeek.com/351978/using-windows-10s-new-clipboard-history-and-cloud-sync/

Comment: running procmon I see it opening `"C:\Windows\SystemApps\InputApp_cw5n1h2txyewy\WindowsInternal.ComposableShell.Experiences.TextInput.InputApp.exe"` with some arguments, but even copying and running the command line doesn't open the clipboard

Comment: How do you even find that in procmon? As soon as I leave it open for a fraction of a second I get about 50k events.

Comment: You have to right click on things and exclude them. Typically exclude processes you know aren't what you're looking for. It will still generate a ton of events.